# turn on colorbar programmatically in clustergram

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I know that one can insert a colorbar by clicking the colorbar icon in the `clustergram` GUI. Is there a way to do it programmatically?
I tried

```
cgo = clustergram(data)
colorbar;
```

This makes a colorbar in a new figure window.  How can a colorbar be created with proper positioning in a `clustergram` figure as if the button was clicked?

Comment: the colorbar is in the same figure of clustergram in your code

Comment: @lennon310 That's weird, it show up in different figure window on two of my computers running 64bit 2013b on windows...

Comment: For me it shows up in the same figure, but it messes up the positioning of the dendogram and the heat map no matter what `Location` is specified.  There is quite a lot of logic in `HeatMap.plot>showColorbar` (toolbox/bioinfo/microarray/@HeatMap/plot.m) just to get the position right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a function buried away (`HeatMap.plot>showColorbar`) that neatly positions the `colorbar` to the left of both the heat map and the dendogram (the lines). Just running `colorbar(...)` will mess up the relative positioning of the dendogram and the heatmap. So you need to somehow run the callback or carefully duplicate all of the position computations.  It's easier to just run the callback.  Here's how.

To create the `colorbar` programmatically for a `clustergram`, *and keep the color bar button in sync*, you need to use the button's assigned callback and set the button's state.

Create the `clustergram`:

```
load filteredyeastdata
cgo = clustergram(yeastvalues(1:30,:),'Standardize','Row');
```

Get the handle for color bar button:

```
cbButton = findall(gcf,'tag','HMInsertColorbar');
```

Get callback (`ClickedCallback`) for the button:

```
ccb = get(cbButton,'ClickedCallback')
ccb = 
    @insertColorbarCB
    [1x1 clustergram]
```

That gives us a handle to the function assigned by the callback (`@insertColorbarCB`), and the function's third input argument (the `clustergram` object). The button's handle and an empty event object are implicitly the first two arguments.

Change the button state to `'on'` (clicked down):

```
set(cbButton,'State','on')
```

Run the callback to create the colorbar:

```
ccb{1}(cbButton,[],ccb{2})
```

Note that the button `State` must be changed to `'on'` *first*, otherwise the callback won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I just managed to solve this problem.
What I did:

I added this function to the clustergram code (I put it at line 1486)

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    function insertColorbarCBALWAYS(obj)

         hFig= gcbf;

         obj.Colorbar = true;

    end
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

and then at line 415 of the clustergram.m file I added this line of code

insertColorbarCBALWAYS(obj);

to call the above function. Save and go: now the colorbar will always be there, once the clustergram is drawn.
Previous method was not working for me so I made this workaround.
One may even save the new clustergram code as clustergramCM such that you can draw cgram in both ways.